# Overlaying Multiple Density Plots in ggplot2 for Panel Data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently working on visualizing panel data in R using ggplot2 and encountering difficulty overlaying multiple density plots onto a single plot. Specifically, I aim to generate density plots for variable Ys for each idvar, and then overlay them with density plots for variable Yhat's, each corresponding to a different idvar and depicted in a different color.

I've attempted to create a minimal reproducible example to illustrate the issue. Below is the code generating the panel data:

```
require(prodest)
sim_data <- panelSim(N= 100, T = 1000)

sim_data <- sim_data %>% 
  select(idvar, Y) %>% 
  mutate(Yhat = Y + 2)
```

The final output should be something like this, with the two plots combined: [image]

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are looking for something like this:

```r
library(prodest)
library(tidyverse)

panelSim(N = 100, T = 1000, alphaL = 0.1, sigomg = 0.5, rho = 0.3) %>% 
  select(idvar, Y) %>% 
  mutate(Yhat = Y + 2) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, group = interaction(idvar, name))) +
  geom_line(stat = 'density', aes(color = name), linewidth = 0.2) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c('#acd7e5', '#0000ff')) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linewidth = 1)))
```

[image]